# (CCNA Cisco) Problemas con Rutas estáticas

Tags: redes

Buen dia, Tengo el siguiente esquema con ip 172.16.20.0 con los segmentos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se puede hacer ping dentro de cada segmento, pero no a otro, lo que es logico. He intentado solucionarlo con rutas estaticas pero al parecer no me funciona no entiendo muy bien como aplicarlo para este caso. O tambien puede ser equivocaciones en mis ip y mascaras que he configurado. Por favor si alguien me pudiera explicar como poder conectar(mas concretamente) entre segmentos con rutas estaticas se lo agradeceria mucho. Le pido disculpas si he tenido alguna equivocacion demasiado simple. Estoy en aprendizaje.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hola, las IPs y máscaras están bien, puedes enseñarnos las rutas que has intentado?

Answer (score 3):

Debes configurar, en cada router, las rutas que no están directamente conectadas a él. Y debes poner como destino el otro router. Quedaría algo así:

```
R1# configure terminal
R1(config)# ip route 172.16.20.32 255.255.255.248 172.16.20.42
```

```
R2# configure terminal
R2(config)# ip route 172.16.20.0 255.255.255.224 172.16.20.41
```

Y no te olvides de poner la gateway por defecto en los PCs, de otra forma no podrían comunicarse entre ellos. Para PC A sería `172.16.20.3`, y para PC B, `172.16.20.33`.